# C# Is it bad practice to provide extra outputs in a separate output parameter?

Tags: c#, output

I have a method with the following signature:

```
bool DoSomething();
```

I want to change it to this:

```
bool DoSomething(IList<int> newIDs);
```

The boolean and the list of IDs are not related to each other. The new method contains an extra output that contains the list of new IDs. Is this bad practice? What is the right way to return multiple values in this situation?

Comment: This is a very subjective question, and `DoSomething()` gives us no clue as to whether your solution is sound or not.  If the primary purpose of this method is to get these IDs, then I'd suggest a signature like `IEnumerable<int> DoSomething()`.

Comment: The boolean and IDs are not related to each other.

Answer (score 6):

You could also "wrap" all the return values inside an object:

```
public class Payload
{
    public List<int> NewIDs { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}

//Use Payload class

public Payload DoSomething(...){...}
```

I think it's important to understand what the semantics of the returned values are before deciding on a specific pattern. If you edit your question with details, I'll provide more insight as well.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

There is a common pattern called the TryParse pattern that is used extensively within the C# Base Class Library which is basically the same as your function signature.

For example: [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static bool TryParse(
    string s,
    out DateTime result
)
```

I think it is fine to use this provided you include the 'out' keyword.

Edit:

Also give the function a name that makes it clear why it returns a null.

Comment: You are completely guessing at the OP's situation.

Comment: Yes, I had assumed the boolean meant success or failure. If this is not the intention and it looks like it isn't, then I would not recommend doing this and would endorse Luc's answer.